# Setting Proxy Configuration in Latest Version of NX: Issues with project.json and proxyConfig.js

Tags: proxy, configuration, nrwl-nx

I'm working with the latest version of NX and I'm trying to set up a proxy configuration. Previously, I was able to accomplish this by modifying the project.json file and setting up a proxyConfig.js file. However, this method no longer seems to be working with the newest version of NX.

Here is the relevant portion of my project.json file:

```json
"serve": {
    "executor": "@nrwl/web:dev-server",
    "defaultConfiguration": "local",
    "options": {
        "buildTarget": "comp:build"
    },
    "configurations": {
        "development": {
            "buildTarget": "comp:build:development"
        },
        "test": {
            "buildTarget": "comp:build:test"
        },
        "local": {
            "buildTarget": "comp:build:local",
            "hmr": true,
            "proxyConfig": "apps/comp/proxyConfig.js"
        },
        "production": {
            "buildTarget": "comp:build:production"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my proxyConfig.js:

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
    '/nedit': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4200/edit',
        secure: false,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
            proxyRes.headers['Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy'] = 'same-origin';
            proxyRes.headers['Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy'] = 'require-corp';
        },
    },
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Despite this setup, it seems the proxy configuration is not being applied as expected. Could anyone guide me on how to set up a proxy configuration in the latest version of NX? If there are changes to be made in these files, or if there is a new way to setup the proxy configuration, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I've tried to set up a proxy configuration in the latest version of NX using the same method that worked in previous versions. This method involved modifying the project.json file to include a proxyConfig option pointing to a proxyConfig.js file. The proxyConfig.js file included the specific proxy settings I wanted to apply.

Comment: I think your question will better be addressed by Nx team on Github. This can be a bug (because you mention it used to work before)

Answer (score 0):

You can use verbose option to see proxy calls.

`nx run app-name:serve --verbose`.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22112?ref=the-full-stack-engineer